# Make application's forms independent from Screen resolution

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing an application on vb.net 2013.

On my pc I'm using my screen resolution as a standard for Form's size , and object's size inside forms.

Of course , on my pc all the forms looks as should be.

But if try to run the application on a greater resolution , the forms and objects are small and the text almost unreadable . If I try to run on a smaller resolution , the forms became larger and objects and text very ugly.

Is there any technique or tool , in order to design form's independent from screen resolution ?

Thank you !

Comment: [Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/)

Comment: You could work out some ratios and then set the values accordingly w.r.t. other resolutions. Of course, that might be a tedious job.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry , what these properties have to do with screen resolution ? Using them , can't stop the form to become smaller when screen resolution is increased.

Comment: @Havirstrechko They'd let you stretch things out by resizing the window.  But it's not really a solution on its own because you still have to deal with font sizes and the like.  I think you'll probably find this problem is easier to deal with in WPF than Windows Forms.

Comment: @Casey My application is Winform not WPF.

Comment: Use TableLayoutPanels and FlowLayoutPanels form the contents rather than explicit form locations.  On a high res screen, the form will look too small to them too - they will make it bigger.  When they do the TLPs can will resize to fit

Comment: @Havirstrechko Yes, I understood that, but I couldn't really discern from your post if it's too far along to reconsider so I thought I'd raise it as something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that Resize the chosen form and all its controls depended on screen resolution change (from the design screen resolution)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FormResizer

    'Considerations:
    'Change the Form AutoSize Mode to None.
    Private f_HeightRatio As New Single()
    Private f_WidthRatio As New Single()

    Public Sub ResizeForm(ByVal ObjForm As Form, ByVal DesignerWidth As Integer, ByVal DesignerHeight As Integer)
        '#Region "Code for Resizing and Font Change According to Resolution"
        'Specify Here the Resolution Y component in which this form is designed
        'For Example if the Form is Designed at 800 * 600 Resolution then DesignerHeight=600
        Dim i_StandardHeight As Integer = DesignerHeight

        'Specify Here the Resolution X component in which this form is designed
        'For Example if the Form is Designed at 800 * 600 Resolution then DesignerWidth=800
        Dim i_StandardWidth As Integer = DesignerWidth
        Dim i_PresentHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

        'Present Resolution Height
        Dim i_PresentWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

        'Presnet Resolution Width
        f_HeightRatio = CSng(CSng(i_PresentHeight) / CSng(i_StandardHeight))
        f_WidthRatio = CSng(CSng(i_PresentWidth) / CSng(i_StandardWidth))
        ObjForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None

        'Make the Autoscale Mode=None
        ObjForm.Scale(New SizeF(f_WidthRatio, f_HeightRatio))
        For Each c As Control In ObjForm.Controls
            If c.HasChildren Then
                ResizeControlStore(c)
            Else
                c.Font = New Font(c.Font.FontFamily, c.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, c.Font.Style, c.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
            End If
        Next
        ObjForm.Font = New Font(ObjForm.Font.FontFamily, ObjForm.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, ObjForm.Font.Style, ObjForm.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This Function is Used to Change the Font of Controls that are Nested in Other Controls.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="objCtl"></param>
    Public Sub ResizeControlStore(ByVal objCtl As Control)
        If objCtl.HasChildren Then
            For Each cChildren As Control In objCtl.Controls
                If cChildren.HasChildren Then
                    ResizeControlStore(cChildren)
                Else
                    cChildren.Font = New Font(cChildren.Font.FontFamily, cChildren.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, cChildren.Font.Style, cChildren.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
                End If
            Next
            objCtl.Font = New Font(objCtl.Font.FontFamily, objCtl.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, objCtl.Font.Style, objCtl.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
        Else
            objCtl.Font = New Font(objCtl.Font.FontFamily, objCtl.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, objCtl.Font.Style, objCtl.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
        End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

and you can use it at the main form load event like this as here the design screen resolution is 800*600 :

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Resizer As New FormResizer
    Resizer.ResizeForm(Me, 800, 600)
    Resizer.ResizeForm(My.Forms.Form2,800,600)
    'etc
End Sub
```

Note : It will not auto resize new controls added at runtime. you will have to call (ResizeControlStore) sub for each new control added like this :

```
Dim Resizer As New FormResizer
Resizer.ResizeControlStore(Btn1)
```